# C programming - Expressions?

Tags: c

I am having trouble understanding the following C programming code. Why is this function important in my program? I am talking about the `[A-Za-z.......]`. Sorry if this is a stupid question. Thanks for your help.

```
int readResults(loebsdata2017 *results, FILE *fp){

    return fscanf(fp, "%[^ ] \"%[A-Za-z \' -]\" %d %[A-Z] %[A-Z] %s %s ", results->loebsnavn, results->rytternavn,
                                                                          &results->rytteralder, results->rytterhold, results->nationalitet,
                                                                          results->rank, results->tid);
}
```

Comment: Did you check the man page?

Comment: What's the man page?

Comment: What's the details of data structure `loebsdata2017`?

Comment: `fscanf` takes a pattern used to parse the input it reads.  The details of how you express these patterns is in the documentation.  This site is not a replacement for reading the documentation.

Comment: I've tried Google, but thanks for your help @SouravGhosh

Comment: In that case, please show what you tried and which part you don't understand.

Comment: Kindly show your research / debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: `scanf` format specifiers are no expression as the title of your question implies.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument of an `fscanf` is the format of what is being scanned. This type of format is present in many similar functions like `printf`, `scanf`, and so on.

To know more about this format check the manual pages (man pages) in Linux by typing:

```
man fscanf
```

on the terminal. If in Windows, check their [manual pages](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjj0NnVl9DYAhWEWSwKHWfeAQYQFggpMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fcb5kac8b.aspx&usg=AOvVaw0J3fQrVdt7loRwLQaxpdT1).

About the particular `%[A-Za-z \' -]` would mean to recognize anything from A to Z, a to z, blank space, ', or -.